# MATLAB error: complex integer arithmetic is not supported

Tags: matlab, dft

Error using  `.*` 
Complex integer arithmetic is not supported.

```
Error in DFT (line 35)
        J(u,v) = J(u,v) + I(x,y) .*exp(-1i*2*pi.*((u*(x-1)/M)+(v*(y-1)/N)));
```

Comment: We can't help you unless you include some relevant code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error is caused by incompatibility of data type. You are probably working with image which is a *uint8* type data but other arithmetic needs *double*.

I suggest you that convert your signal to *double* firstly. For example, before the loops write this:

```
I = double(I); %// Now your signal is double type

%// ...
%// for loops and calculations
%// ...
```

I hope this would solve your problem..

Comment: If this solves your problem, please mark the answer as accepted (press the tick mark in the upper left)